# Installing Kingsoft on 13.10

Tags: 64-bit, 32-bit, 13.10

I am trying to install Kingsoft in 13.10.  However, a32-libs multi arch support is not longer available.  What do I need to install to run Kingsoft.  I have kingsoft installed, but it will not start without 32bit support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it working .... had to install the following, besides the auto-dependencies:

sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0:i386 libpng12-0:i386 libsm6:i386 libxrender1:i386 libfontconfig1:i386

Comment: IT WORKS :-)  THANK YOU!!!!!!  I asked several times on here and you are the first person to solve it and make it simple.  You are AWESOME!!!